# doctrine2 relationship with three entities

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

i ran into the following problem and after hours of searching on the web i don't find any solution.
I want to have a "3-Entity Relationship" between the Entity Project, User and Role.
A Project have many users, and a User can be member of many projects. But in every Relationship between Project <--> User the User can have a different Role.
How can i solve this with Doctrine2?
Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
An little codeexample would be very nice :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have an N:M association between Project and User. Then every instance of this association has the role property (either as an integer for a fixed list, or as an association to a Role entity). Doctrine unfortunately does not explicitly support properties on associations, so in these cases you should use connector entities: an entity that is in ManyToOne connection to both Project and User. This entity then can hold the role value(s)/association(s), but you have to manage (dis)connecting through these objects.